# How do I check the size of the data file before I upload it (Flutter)

Tags: ios, flutter, file, mobile, filepath

When I take the file I want the data file size information, in the future the upload file limit will be made based on the file size. the following code that I use

```html
void _openFileExplorer() async {
    setState(() => _loadingPath = true);
    try {
      _directoryPath = null;
      _paths = (await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
        type: _pickingType,
        allowMultiple: _multiPick,
        allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'png', 'jpeg'],
      ))
          ?.files;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Unsupported operation" + e.toString());
    } catch (ex) {
      print(ex);
    }
    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      _loadingPath = false;
      _fileName = _paths != null ? _paths.map((e) => e.name).toString() : '...';
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

you can get file size using function named **lengthSync**.

just use this function like

```
var size = file.lengthSync()
```

it will give file size in bytes.

Comment: Do I need to do permission for iOS?, I tried the code and the information that appears is the following:
Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot retrieve length of file, path = '(20201223160946.pdf)'

Comment: u need to give universal path for the file. you are using only file name in the path you need to give whole path to get file.

Comment: you can test with asset file